# apache drill Does admin priviledge required for updating storage

Tags: apache-drill

Hey I am newbie working on apache drill but I am unable to update storage plugin in it, I read somewhere that I need to have admin priviledge to update storage. How can it be done

Comment: Which user you have logged in as? Its either admin privilege or the file where the storage is being written doesnt have apache write permission

Comment: You need admin privilege to update storage plugin. You can give admin privileges to users/groups. Refer 
to 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-web-console-and-rest-api-security/#setting-up-web-console-administrators-and-administrator-user-groups
.
More on admin user privileges - Refer to 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/roles-and-privileges/